# Better SQL Replace

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, query-optimization

I wanted to know if there is a better way of writing this Update.

```
update Alumni_Export_New
set phone = replace(replace(replace(replace(phone,'-',''),' ',''),')',''),'(','')
from tbl
```

I have a stored procedure in MSSQL 2005 to clean the phone field in a table and thought there should be a better way of doing this then what I have.

Comment: What flavour of SQL are you using?

Comment: It doesn't solve the replace "problem" but have you considered using a trigger doing the cleaning io a stored procedure? The cleaning would happen immediatly compared to whatever schedule you use in running the sp.

Answer (score 2):

Use [CLR integration and Regular Expressions](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/tsql-regular-expression-workbench/).

Comment: While valid, most shops do not allow CLR functions sadly.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider putting the replace logic in a user defined function if you really don't like the look the `REPLACE` and if you don't mind a performance hit.  Otherwise, what you have is probably your best solution.

**Sample:**

```
UPDATE Alumni_Export_New
SET phone = dbo.StripPhoneNumber(phone)
FROM tbl
```

Comment: I have a number of other queries the will all be run at the same time so I thought this SP would be best. Also I am calling this form a Coldfusion script. What are the advantages of a UDF over SP when being called form an application?

Comment: @MisterBigs - I was just thinking of the replace logic itself.  You can keep the stored procedure, but call the function as a part of your `UPDATE`.  I've updated the post to describe.

Comment: the replace would not be call by itself anywhere else but in this SP so I guess the UDF is not needed. It looks messy to me but I guess I'll keep it as is.

Comment: Doesn't really improve things, just moves the logic into a function.  Easier if writing UPDATE/etc by hand, but will make updating the format a pain

Answer (score 0):

If using Microsoft SQl Server, you should write a user defined function (UDF) to do this

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is for MySQL, I don't think there is an alternative to the REPLACE() function for multiple arguments (such as TRANSLATE() in other dbs).

Answer (score 0):

On the Oracle you can use translate function.

```
update Alumni_Export_New set phone = translate(phone, '- ()', '') from tbl
```

Comment: Good to know, but the OP uses Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: Also, not a direct replacement for the OP's query -- which replaces each character, not all of them together.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considering make loop trough all string, if you need only numeric chars inside i

```
    CREATE FUNCTION fn_retun_only_numbers
(
    @myOrgString varchar(50)
)
RETURNS  varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    declare @lenOfString int, @i int
    declare @oneChar varchar(1),@newString varchar(50)


    set @lenOfString = (select len(@myOrgString))
    set @i = 1
    set @newString= ''

    while  (@lenOfstring>=@i)
    begin
    set @oneChar = substring(@myOrgString,@i,1)

if ((@oneChar)in ('0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'))
begin
set @newString=@newString+@oneChar
end
set @i=@i+1
end
return @newString
END
GO
```

And so as other mentioned you can  now

```
update Alumni_Export_New
set phone = dbo.fn_retun_only_numbers(phone)
from tbl
```

*I do not have SQL at home so maybe there is some mistakes in code*

This is not maybe the best solution but if you need to be sure to always get only numbers
maybe this is one of possible approach